# Why the file from which I am trying to import data from is opened?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import data from an existing Excel file to another file.
I use the ADO function when the connection string and the SQL query arrive from variables.

See example:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = Sheets("DASYSTEM").Range("E12").Value

Dim DaSystemCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim DaData As ADODB.Recordset

Set DaSystemCon = New ADODB.Connection
Set DaData = New ADODB.Recordset

DaSystemCon.ConnectionString = Trim(Sheets("DASYSTEM").Range("E11").Value)
DaSystemCon.Open

With DaData
.ActiveConnection = DaSystemCon
.Source = sql
.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
.Open
End With
```

The function run from file X import the data to the same file ( file X ) and imports the data from file Y.
Both files are on the network ( windows server ).

When Y file is opened by Other user on the network and another user tries to execute the function in an X file, the Y file is opened during the run.
If the Y file is not open by another user, the import runs from the X file is executed in the background and does not open the Y file.

How can I avoid this?
I mean, how I cause the procedure in any case not to open the Y file even if it is open by another user on the network.
Thanks

Comment: Is sharing your file not an option?

Comment: Can you share what `Trim(Sheets("DASYSTEM").Range("E11").Value` equates to please.

Comment: If you want to enter a room and the door is closed, how can you avoid opening the door and yet enter the room?

Comment: What is your sql?   Test   .LockType =  adLockPessimistic , .CursorType = adOpenKeyset